# EasyAdmin on Server - Problem with the /admin route

Tags: nginx, server, symfony5, easyadmin

I have some strange problem with easyadmin 3 on my web server. On my local machine everything works perfectly, but when I deployed the code to the web server, I am getting this error:

The signature of the URL is not valid.

In log file it looks like this:

request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: "The signature of the URL is not valid." at /var/www/myapp/vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/EventListener/AdminRouterSubscriber.php line 134 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException(code: 0): The signature of the URL is not valid. at /var/www/myapp/vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/EventListener/AdminRouterSubscriber.php:134)"} []

If I debug the routes, the route /admin exist:

**Name                     Method Scheme Host Path**

app_admin_dashboard_index  ANY  ANY    ANY  /admin

Does somebody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding this code to the DashboardController:

```
public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->disableUrlSignatures()
            ;
    }
```

Comment: It's not a very good decision to disable signature. Better to find what's wrong with it and resolve a problem.